# There is no Options on my list

Tags: android

Im trying to set up a preferences but there is no options on the list here is the code

```
<ListPreference 
android:title="list"
android:key="list"
android:summary= "This is a list to choose from"
android:entries="@array/list"
android:entryValues="@array/lvalues"
/>
```

Here is the code for the array

```
<string-array name="list">
    <item Option="1"></item>
    <item Option="2"></item>
    <item Option="3"></item>
    <item Option="4"></item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="lvalues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</string-array>
```

I want it to say Option 1 etc next to the thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you where trying to do?

```
<string-array name="list">
   <item>Option 1</item>
   <item>Option 2</item>
   <item>Option 3</item>
   <item>Option 4</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="lvalues">
   <item>1</item>
   <item>2</item>
   <item>3</item>
   <item>4</item>
</string-array>
```

### String Array

An array of strings that can be referenced from the application.

**Note:** A string array is a simple resource that is referenced using the value provided in the name attribute (not the name of the XML file). As such, you can combine string array resources with other simple resources in the one XML file, under one `<resources>` element.

### ELEMENTS

`<string-array>`
Defines an array of strings. Contains one or more  elements.

**attributes:**

***name***

- String. A name for the array. This name will be used as the resource ID to reference the array.

`<item>`

- A string, which can include styling tags. The value can be a reference to another string resource. Must be a child of a `<string-array>` element. Beware that you must escape apostrophes and quotation marks.

**No attributes.**

This application code retrieves a string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Reference/Source:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: You had written it as an **attribute** to the `<item>` element, which isn't allowed since `<item>` doesn't have any attributes.